# What does Oracle Data Access Components Release number mean?

Tags: oracle

I need to document the Oracle Data Access Component installed on our system.
The current version we have installed is `12.1.0.1.2`.

What does each number indicate ?

I searched but could only find [Identifying Your Oracle Database Software Release](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba004.htm#ADMIN11032)

Comment: What about the provided link is lacking when it comes to answering your question?

Comment: ODAC is a client component. But I felt some of the numbers such as `Application Server Release Number` were not for client components